# How to get the perfect square for the following equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system

The problem is defined as follows:
$$
\min_X tr(X^T A X)-\alpha tr(X^T B)
$$
I want to get the equal perfect square equation as that above, that is
$$
\min_X \| X-C\|_F^2
$$ 
where $C$ is related to $A$ and $B$. 
Is it possible? How to derive the perfect square equation?

**UPDATED:**
This problem is from [this paper](https://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/AAAI/AAAI14/paper/view/8222/8908).
In Eqn. (15), the authors have derived a Lagrange function, but I'm not sure whether the following term in Eqn. (15) is right when optimizing the $J_n$.
From the Eqn. (15), we have
$$
\min_{J_n} \sum_{n=1}^{N}\|J_n\|_* + \lambda \|J_n^T(W_b-\alpha B_n)J_n\|_F^2 -tr(V_2^TJ_n) +\frac{\mu}{2}\|U_n-J_n\|_F^2
$$
The authors have wrote an equal optimization problem in the first equation of Eqn. (16) of the paper. But I was confused with it for a long time. And I also made a post in [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1036317/how-to-merge-similar-terms-to-get-a-perfect-square-form) to ask for a favor, but @user1551 also thought the term $\lambda \|J_n^T(W_b-\alpha B_n)J_n\|_F^2$ in the equation above couldn't be changed into the perfect square form in Eqn. (16).

Thus, I've tried to change the term $\lambda \|J_n^T(W_b-\alpha B_n)J_n\|_F^2$ into $\lambda tr(J_n^T(W_b-\alpha B_n)J_n)$, and make a derivation as follows:

[image]

But I still couldn't get the perfect square form. Thus I made this post for your kind help. If convenient, could you help derive it, please?

Comment: Unless $A=I$ (or at least $\operatorname{tr} (X^T AX) = \operatorname{tr} (X^T X)$) I don't see how you could do this.

Comment: @copper.hat, thank you.

Comment: The addition changes things entirely. In that second term, $J_n$ appears twice within the squared Frobenius norm. Thus $J_n$ is involved in a *quartic* fashion. Your attempt to change it to a trace fails to preserve equivalence; your trace is just quadratic in $J_n$.

Comment: I am sure the authors would agree this is a non-convex problem. Indeed, the convex-analysis tag isn't even appropriate here. Nonlinear-programming, perhaps, but certainly not convex-optimization.

Comment: @MichaelGrant, yes, the $J_n$ is involved in quartic fashion, but in Eqn. (16), the $J_n$ is quadratic, thus I don't know how the quartic $J_n$ is changed to quadratic $J_n$.

Comment: (16) are the optimality conditions, and they are not independent. (For instance, $U_n$ depends on $J_n$, and vice versa.) That's going to be no easier to solve. I'm officially off the case. You should contact the authors.

Comment: @MichaelGrant, thanks. I could derive other optimization equations in Eqn. (16) except the optimization equation for $J_n$, thus I thought there were some tricks in the derivation of the perfect square for $J_n$.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by copper.hat, this is not always possible.

In particular, in your second problem, there is no coupling between the different entries in the array $X$. In particular, each entry $X_{ij}$ solves the one-dimensional problem
$$\min_{X_{ij}} (X_{ij} - C_{ij})^2.$$

In the general case, this decoupling is not possible for the first problem.

Comment: thank you for replying! In fact, I meet this problem in a paper and I'm not sure how the authors get the perfect square.

Comment: Maybe you want to give a reference for that paper? Is there some structure in $A$?

Comment: thank you! I've updated the post above and give the reference link. If convenient, could you help derive the problem, please?

Answer (score 0):

The other commenters are correct, in that you can't get it precisely into the form you've shown. But you can get a perfect square, if that's all you're after, as long as $A$ is positive definite. Let $A^{1/2}$ be the symmetric square root of $A$. Then
$$\begin{aligned}
&\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(X^TAX)-\alpha\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(X^TB) 
= \langle A^{1/2}X,A^{1/2}X\rangle - \alpha\langle A^{1/2}X,A^{-1/2}B\rangle\\
&\qquad = \langle A^{1/2}X-\tfrac{\alpha}{2}A^{-1/2}B,A^{1/2}X-\tfrac{\alpha}{2}A^{-1/2}B\rangle
-\tfrac{\alpha^2}{4}\langle A^{-1/2}B,A^{-1/2}B\rangle \\
&\qquad \|A^{1/2}X-\tfrac{\alpha}{2}A^{-1/2}B\|_F^2-\tfrac{\alpha^2}{4}\|A^{-1/2}B\|_F^2
\end{aligned}
$$
You can drop the constant term in the optimization, and you have
$$\min_X \|A^{1/2} X-\tfrac{\alpha}{2}A^{-1/2}B\|_F^2$$
If you're wiling to change variables to $Y=A^{1/2}X$, you now have
$$\min_Y \|Y-\tfrac{\alpha}{2}A^{-1/2}B\|_F^2$$

Comment: Hi, Prof. Grant, Thank you very much for replying my question again! I've updated the post above and give the reference link. If convenient, could you help check it, please?